# WCF Service Reference does not reuse types in existing assemblies (VS 2010 Beta 2)

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

I'm looking for the best approach to share types (the actual classes, not proxies) between a WCF service and a client.  To that end, I defined the classes in a separate assembly that both service and client reference.  I selected "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies" when generating the service reference in the client, but References.cs is generated with proxies for all classes.

This is exactly the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930124/reuse-types-in-current-assembly-for-wcf-proxies), but I don't know how to implement the accepted solution.  One difference is that I'm using VS 2010 Beta 2.

> import the complete service contract
>   in code form

or

> create your own ClientBase-derived class. It's really very easy

Assuming this is the best approach, I would appreciate a good link that covers how to do this.  Is the approach outlined in the linked answer the best one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I did two things in the same step.  Not sure if one or both resolved the problem:

1. Added a [DataContract(Namespace="My.Shared.Assemblys.Namespace")] to *one* of the classes in the shared assembly.
2. Restarted VS 2010 Beta 2

Comment: I had the exact same problem today with VS2012 Update 1. After changing the `DataContracts` multiple times first one, later all types were no longer reused. Restarting VS had helped...

Comment: VS 2012 - a simple reboot fixed it for me

Comment: Same with VS 2010 Pro

Comment: For me it was opening a opening my VS2010 project in VS2013 and then 'update service references'.

Comment: I all of the sudden had an issue with reuse, while other services using the same type had no issues.
Explicit Namespace helped - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, but the I forgot to build assembly with DataContracts for client and thus it was generating it's own contracts. Once I've rebuilt the assembly - it reused them.

Comment: Rebuild of the referenced assembly + "Update Service Reference" helped!

Answer (score 1):

My issue with VS2010 SP1 was trying to use a class that derived from `Dictionary<T,U>` with a `CollectionDataContract` attribute. Seems VS won't reuse the type... I also tried Eric's suggestion above, but it didn't work.