# WCF reuse types in referenced assemblies does not reuse the ServiceContract Interface

Tags: interface, wcf

I have four separate projects:

- **MyUserControl** - Needs a reference to a service implementing `IMyService`
- **MyService** - Implements `IMyService`
- **MySharedInterfaces** -  Contains `IMyUserControl` and `IMyService`
- **MyWebApp**

The user control needs to be dynamically loaded at runtime. This implements `IMyUserControl` and has a property of type `IMyService` which will be set at runtime.

The trouble is even with the option to reuse types, MyWebApp isn't reusing the `IMyService` interface. It always generates it again from the Service Reference. This wouldn't be an issue if I could cast it to `MySharedInterfaces.IMyService`, which I can't understand, since it should be exactly the same.

The user control is expecting something of type `IMyService`. Is there anyway to either cast the `WebServiceReference.IMyService` back to `MySharedInterface.IMyService` or force the `WebServiceReference` to reuse the `MySharedInterface.IMyService`?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Reuse existing types" is ignored when adding a service reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134064/reuse-existing-types-is-ignored-when-adding-a-service-reference)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119329/wcf-service-reference-generates-its-own-contract-interface-wont-reuse-mine/17318813#17318813

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Matt, you could definitely do the "two-step" process of creating the client-side proxy yourself - it's really not a biggie.

In your client app, reference the `MySharedInterfaces` assembly. Then, create an instance of the `ChannelFactory<T>` for your service interface:

```
ChannelFactory<IMyService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>();
```

This basically creates a factory class which is then capable of creating actual communcations channels between your client and your server. Since it requires the service contract, this method only works if you can share the service contract assembly (which you can and want, in your case).

This is a fairly time- and resource-expensive step, so if ever possible, try to stash the factory somewhere and reuse it instead of continuously re-creating it.

Given your channel factory, you can now create your actual communication channels, which is basically equivalent to your proxy client that gets generated by `Add Service Reference`:

```
IMyService client = factory.CreateChannel();
```

This is not a very expensive operation, so you could do this every time before making a service call, and not worry about faulted channels and so forth.

The `client` also implements the `ICommunicationObject` interface, so if you need to check something WCF related, like the state of the channel, you can cast your client:

```
CommunicationState currentState = ((ICommunicationObject)client).State;
```

So you basically really have all the bits and pieces of your generated client proxy class, but you have more control over what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

Have you included a reference to MySharedInterfaces in MyUserControl? Does MySharedInterfaces have any references to other assemblies, which are not referenced in MyUserControl?

The hard way is not using the generated Service Reference and to use ChannelFactory. This gives you always the interface from MySharedInterfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The MyUserControl project references MySharedInterfaces, and there's nothing referenced by MySharedInterfaces which isn't referenced by MyUserControl. At the moment it's just a proof of concept, so it's pretty empty at the moment.

Last week was the first time I've looked at WCF, so was hoping to stick to the easy stuff to start with. I'll have a read up on ChannelFactory though. Just out of curiosity, why can't it reuse the IMyServiceInterface when it can reuse everything else?