# WCF single point-of-contact

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

WCF beginner's question: I've been told that changing the WCF contract is costly and requires constant maintenance (recreating the proxy in the client side), and therefore the preferred method is having one very generic point-of-contact method (which decides how to act, say, according to a given enum parameter).

This sounds quite smelly to me, but I haven't been able to find any information about this issue (bad choice of search keywords? probably).
Any advice, or maybe a useful link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to generate the proxy again, you can simply ensure the client is built with the correct interface version.  If you're very careful and only add methods, not remove or modify, that works just fine too.  That's a lot of responsibility to manage, of course.

To use an interface rather than generate a client proxy, check my question from a while ago:

[WCF Service Reference generates its own contract interface, won't reuse mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119329/wcf-service-reference-generates-its-own-contract-interface-wont-reuse-mine)

Comment: +1: Expanding a contract does not break backwards compatibility. No need to regenerate the proxy if the client isn't using any of the new methods on the contract.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing some terms here and I think you might be referring to a known flaw which has been fixed in .Net 3.5 SP1.

Recreating the WCF proxy used to be an expensive operation at runtime.  This has been improved in .Net 3.5 to cache the proxy objects transparently [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/27/performance-improvement-of-wcf-client-proxy-creation-and-best-practices.aspx).

If you are referring to the "code maintenance" of the proxy, then all you are referring to is implementing an interface at the client.  If you need to maintain the interface then this comes back to basic SOA.  If your services provide access and as much information as possible, assuming that your service will be used for purposes you haven't yet considered then you will likely not need to modify the interface after it is created.  You should also consider your upgrade paths as well.

Juval Lowy has a good discussion about this problem in his book which is a little dense but has some pretty good information in it.

A piece of advice:  WCF has a whole lot of features designed to make your code really simple and elegant.  If you are worreid about maintenance, what you may be driven to do is write an interface:

```
string ServiceMethod(string xml) //returns XML
```

Don't do this.  Take the time to design a good maintainable interface and a good data/message contract.  This will let WCF provide all the extras you get for free when hosting your service for interaction.

Answer (score 2):

Generic (as in non-specific, monolithic) interfaces are hard to understand and program to. The reason not to define a single method as the API is that it's impossible for clients to understand what's going on, and when you change the (implicit) API of this interface, your clients will break in horrible ways that you won't detect at compile time.

It's been a while since I touched WCF, but if your clients are internal (same codebase, versioning and deployment schemes), then regenerating the WCF proxies is very easy, and having a "strong" detailed API will make your life so much easier than a generic one.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of change you mean. Change to the service contract is indeed costly and should not happen. Service contracts are (or should be) at a sufficiently high level of granularity that change is very rare.

More common are changes to the types which are exposed on the service. These changes are more common and therefore you do need to approach your change in such a way as to avoid breaking existing clients if possible.

There are several ways you can do this, such as exposing your types polymorphically using an interface, but the simplest way is to simply ensure that changes to your types on add new data member fields and make the new fields non-mandatory. If you can limit your changes to these then this is has the lowest impact to existing clients and enables new clients to use the new fields.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is true that modifying the service contract (interface) would also required the client to recreate the proxy class at their end using the new published WSDL and may even require the client to change their code as par the new proxy. I don't think you can create such a generic interface that can handle all changes further down the road in the contract. A contract has to be written very carefully so that it doesn't change often and if there is a need to change the contract then it is better to deploy the service with a different version so that your old client can still work with the old version.